# Merge two linked lists without duplicities

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Given two sorted linked lists, where the result should be union without duplicates.

- Creating of new nodes is not allowed.
- The resulting list will be composed of the elements of the original lists.

Inputs are two lists separated by empty line:

L1 -> 2 3 3 4 4 4 5

L2 -> 3 4 5 5 6 7

Result -> 2 3 4 5 6 7

I have my solution below, but creating new node in **Union** function.

Is there any simple way how to change **Union** function with the logic of not creating any new node and remove duplicates?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, next = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

def PrintLinkedList( p ):
    print( "Result:", end=" " )
    while p!=None:
        print( p.data, end=" " )
        p = p.next
    print(".")

def ReadLinkedList():
    first = None
    last = None
    r = input()
    while r!="":
        row = r.split()
        if len(row)==0:
            break
        for s in row:
            p = Node(int(s),None)
            if first==None:
                first = p
            else:
                last.next = p
            last = p
        r = input()
    return first

def dedup(head):
    current = head
    while current:
        runner = current
        # Check, until runner.next is not None.
        while runner.next:
            if current.data == runner.next.data:
                runner.next = runner.next.next
            else:
                runner = runner.next
        current = current.next

def Union(a, b):

    # A dummy node to store the result
    dummyNode = Node(0)
    headA = a
    headB = b

    # Tail stores the last node
    tail = dummyNode
    while True:

        # If any of the list gets completely empty
        # directly join all the elements of the other list
        if headA is None:
            tail.next = headB
            break
        if headB is None:
            tail.next = headA
            break

        # Compare the x of the lists and whichever is smaller is
        # appended to the last of the merged list and the head is changed
        if headA.data <= headB.data:
            tail.next = headA
            headA = headA.next
        else:
            tail.next = headB
            headB = headB.next

        # Advance the tail
        tail = tail.next

    # Delete dups and returns the head of the merged list
    dedup(dummyNode.next)
    return dummyNode.next
```

Comment: You can just reuse nodes of any list when doing merge. Instead of creating new node, just use node of any of two lists. Because according to task you're allowed to modify given lists, hence their nodes can be used/modified for any purpose that you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest dealing with the first node separately, so you know what the head will be of the merged list. The rest of your code can remain the same:

```
def Union(a, b):
    if a is None or b is None:  # Deal with this trivial case
         a = a or b
         dedup(a)
         return a

    headA = a
    headB = b

    # Tail stores the last node: process first node
    if headA.data <= headB.data:
        tail = headA
        headA = headA.next
    else:
        tail = headB
        headB = headB.next
    head = tail  # Remember what the head is of the merged list
    while True:
        if headA is None:
            tail.next = headB
            break
        if headB is None:
            tail.next = headA
            break
        if headA.data <= headB.data:
            tail.next = headA
            headA = headA.next
        else:
            tail.next = headB
            headB = headB.next

        # Advance the tail
        tail = tail.next

    # Delete dups and returns the head of the merged list
    dedup(head)
    return head
```

Comment: Thank you @trincot! Looks like "Deal with this trivial case" doesn't work properly. If you have L1 empty and L2 not empty, it should return L2.

Comment: Ah sorry, it assumed that `dedup` would *return* the resulting  list too. I now see your function doesn't return anything. So I have corrected that case. You still might want to actually return also in `dedup`. It allows to write shorter code.

Comment: My apologies, I overlooked it. Thanks a lot for quick fix!

Answer (score 0):

**Part 1**

Without modifying your solution I decided to implement my own, it doesn't create any new Node. It does a regular merge-sort algorithm. See **Part 2** of my answer for shorter solution.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVTbTsMwDH3vV/htjVRNasZAQtsv8MQbQlVYXRaRpVWacfn64lzWNazwACRSU8fHx/ZJ2u7D7lu9GoadEn0Pd22NtxnQqLGBqpJa2qrKe1RNAbWwogCN7xa2hNTIAtQNh1g6ALnckjpijFuyzDHvDAqLlZK9zVWk0ZHVG01rAEFqMPiKpsd6hJ2hNeZI9TC/bdAejQYd@DsjtU3pZQMKZO9TnJlCmDdR9ROHZ8jVMjSNuqaUC1iwFBBT@AZZSH0QUucxpyoLUJwiHzzuILqcggrqqzvanC37TklaGfP9St@v0M@Yc/aYEiSClaxIN3goKwgxlXGPop7adMh2avvH214qhHtznLTv1CpPcoGg9qmMC/XceKJCXsadhGCMAOou0OnWTijLcGU2W8L615TacbiCpyzO3pwiU3gMMfN1jidO/aty1hXVMhfO9GokbKe7/Q2lyxYwiTueQ2wjdZXBkcSgSg/EKcGjePNi/KAd/5t2/P@147/Rjs9ox4Mj/Gi@fKWuQpbAs/CtZsPAYUXzys915t7WNK/h5hM)

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, next = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

def create_list(l):
    n = None
    for e in reversed(l):
        n = Node(e, n)
    return n

def print_list(l):
    if l is None:
        return
    else:
        print(l.data, end = ' ')
        print_list(l.next)

def main():
    l1, l2 = [list(map(int, input().split())) for i in range(2)]
    l1, l2 = create_list(l1), create_list(l2)
    
    r = None
    head = None
    last = None
    
    while True:
        if l1 is None and l2 is None:
            break
        
        if l2 is None or l1 is not None and l1.data <= l2.data:
            if last is None or last < l1.data:
                if r is None:
                    r = l1
                    head = r
                else:
                    r.next = l1
                    r = r.next
            last = l1.data
            l1 = l1.next
        elif l1 is None or l2.data < l1.data:
            if last is None or last < l2.data:
                if r is None:
                    r = l2
                    head = r
                else:
                    r.next = l2
                    r = r.next
            last = l2.data
            l2 = l2.next

    print_list(head)
            
main()
```

Input:

```
2 3 3 4 4 4 5
3 4 5 5 6 7
```

Output:

```
2 3 4 5 6 7
```

---

**Part 2**

One can notice that in my code above `l1` and `l2` parts of code are symmetrical, hence I made code twice more simple (shorter) by using `l[i]` instead of `l1` and `l2`, where index `i` signifies if we work with `l1` (`l[0]`) or `l2` (`l[1]`). Here is simplified code:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJbbsMgEPz3KfavUFlRHk0rVckVegHLslC8bpAItoD0cXp3F/yI04BkDDM7u7PQ/YZza3d9fzLKe/hoa3zPgEaNDVSVtjpUlfBomhxqFVQOFn8CHIlpUSYqD2asmEAQL0tgiOEly1j55FAFrIz2QZhBxg6qcdO0DhC0BYdf6DzWE22m1iiQ6pHx2GG4Ogs26XdO27CU1w0Y0B5sG2KaWS2ShVklf2hrUn@CJ7kkDGrRi0xZLkpbMcgbCioWtvhzUZ2g2JycdNcg5Mp3RtNKI1rU0aKynyi2skxGcjijqnOgC@GmFVxsCc@wi3D8fJ@1QTDFurx1BCRoik352KVmrU0O67IYSXPQnZCiHvBhutHDMcrGTTnrNanCWx3eH4isE3lOPgS4kb1Eom04xsB/ADeDMLcA0PhHGuNDeyjEGRJjgoYWTwXPAJ2MwBSR3b0Frkwu0mTpRWR9v4UdzZc49xn/7Wm@wtsf)

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, next = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

def create_list(l):
    n = None
    for e in reversed(l):
        n = Node(e, n)
    return n

def print_list(l):
    if l is not None:
        print(l.data, end = ' ')
        print_list(l.next)

def main():
    l = [create_list(list(map(int, input().split()))) for i in range(2)]
    r, head, last = [None] * 3
    
    while l[0] is not None or l[1] is not None:
        i = [1, 0][l[1] is None or l[0] is not None and l[0].data <= l[1].data]
        if last is None or last < l[i].data:
            if r is None:
                r = l[i]
                head = r
            else:
                r.next = l[i]
                r = r.next
        last = l[i].data
        l[i] = l[i].next
    
    print_list(head)
            
main()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Arty, this looks much simpler.

Comment: @Marian Just figured out how to make twice shorter code, read part-2 of my updated answer. This simplification comes from the fact that code for `l1` and `l2` is totally same, thus we can make it twice shorter through `l[i]`, where index `i` signifies if it is list `l1` or `l2`.